# SSH Python Version and Local Python Version is different

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ssh

While doing ssh from my local, the python version in ssh says 2.7.7, whereas my local python version is 3.7.1. ALso, remote system version is 3.6.1. Due to the above Error, unable to load python libraries like pandas.

Should be able to load libraries without any issue....

Comment: When you pass through ssh, your bashrc is not loaded. Try to execute `source ~/.bash_rc` (on linux) to see if it's solve your problem. For windows, maybe an environnement variable as well that is not set.

Comment: Are you using venv or pyenv?

Answer (score 0):

Use PATH to reference to the python path from where you want to read the python version.